# Conditional with JSP tags

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I've got no experience with JSP tags. I'm editing someone's web page (installing a plugin for a table). The table is generated with what seems to be JSP tags.

They've got:

```
<c:forEach items="${row.fields}" var="rowField">
<td><c:out value="${rowField.htmlString}"/></td>
</c:forEach>
```

If `${rowField.htmlString}` (whatever that means) is a text input box (just assume containing 'input' means it's a text box), I need to add a class to the `<td>`.

How? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a class to the `<td>` or the htmlString?

Comment: @josh.trow Add a class to the <td>

Comment: Since this question has an accepted answer, may I assume that the JSTL functions taglib problem as in the answer's comments is been resolved? For the case that you're still struggling with getting JSTL functions to work, please carefully go through our JSTL wiki page. Hover the `[jstl]` tag below the question until you see a popbox and then click the *info* link therein.

Comment: @BalusC no the problem hasn't been 'resolved', but i know what is wrong... and i'm not at liberty to modify the appropriate code. i've figured out a work around instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<c:forEach items="${row.fields}" var="rowField">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${fn:contains(rowField.htmlString, 'input')}">
            <td class="someClass"><c:out value="${rowField.htmlString}"/></td>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <td><c:out value="${rowField.htmlString}"/></td>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: What could this mean: An error occurred while parsing custom action attribute "test" with value "${fn:contains(rowField.htmlString, 'input')}": org.apache.taglibs.standard.lang.jstl.parser.ParseException: EL functions are not supported.

Comment: Probably you didn't declare the `fn` taglib. Do you have this line in your code? `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>`

Comment: Yep I have that. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Have a look at this issue. Looks like similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555094/when-i-mix-jstl-1-0-and-jstl-1-1-taglib-declarations-it-causes-a-parseexception

Comment: @ryanprayogo so it appears I can't use `fn:contains`. Is there any other way of solving my original question (perhaps with regular JSP)?